# The text becomes a clickable link (URL) after sending the email

Tags: email, gmail, amazon-ses

I want to send Database credentials with it's hostname. But when I send the mail, the hostname is coming as url, but it's a text. How to solve it?
ex:

```
        <div class="credentials">
            <p><strong>Hostname:</strong> <span>RDS_ID.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com</span></p>
            <p><strong>Username:</strong> <span>RDS_Username</span></p>
            <p><strong>Password:</strong> <span>RDS_Password</span></p>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved the issue by adding an anchor tag with an empty href attribute. Now the hostname will be interpreted as text rather than a clickable link.

```
<div class="credentials">
            <p><strong>Hostname:</strong> <span><a href="" style="text-decoration:none">RDS_ID.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com</a></span></p>
            <p><strong>Username:</strong> <span>RDS_Username</span></p>
            <p><strong>Password:</strong> <span>RDS_Password</span></p>
</div>
```